# How to find coordinates using Zipcode in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi i want to find coordinates using zipcode in iphone ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapKit doesn't let you do forward geocoding.

I don't know if this is the best alternative, but i have a JSON/XML feed that does it for me. I just submit a NSURLConnection to the script (eg: http://mywebsite.com/feed.php?zipcode=...whatever) and it does all the work using google maps (or another service) and sends me back the coordinates.

A quick google turns this up too - this could help: http://blog.cloudmade.com/2009/06/12/how-to-get-forward-geocoding-in-iphone-mapkit/ this is my solution - but everything is already done for you web side.